# FCM - Sending notification to my android device from Java

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I whish to create a simple Java project which uses FCM.
I found a lot of tutorials on the web, but unfortunately it is not really clear how it works.
I want to write a simple Java code which sends a push notification message to my phone device (android).
I read through the offical FCM website, but I cannot understand how can I make a real connection between my phone and my Java project?
It needs any device ID or token?
How it works?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To *send* FCM messages from Java you can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). See the [documentation on sending messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) for full details.

Note: this will only work from a JVM. It is not possible to use the Admin SDK in an Android project.

Answer (score 0):

A little late my answer, a short code to send a notification from android, using: [FCM-AndroidToOtherDevice](https://github.com/DavidBarbaran/FCM-AndroidToOtherDevice)

```
FirebasePush firebasePush = new FirebasePush("LEGACY_SERVER_KEY");
firebasePush.setNotification(new Notification("title","body"));
firebasePush.sendToTopic("news");
```